# regex match any whitespace

Tags: php, regex

I want to make a replacement using regex and preg_replace function. this is my code

```
$verif = "/wordA(\s*)wordB(?! wordc)/i";
$replacement = 'wordA wordb wordc';
$newvar = preg_replace($verif, $replacement, $article->text);
```

That works if only we have one whitespace between wordA and wordB.
I need to match what ever the number of whitespaces between wordA & wordB.

example:

> wordA (10 or more whitespace)    wordB -> wordA wordb wordc  same wordA(1 whitespace) wordB -> wordA wordb wordc ...

Comment: The `\s*` will work for zero or more spaces.  Also, is there an inherent reason that you have the whitespace and `wordc` in captures?

Comment: Thank you for your responds. Sorry but i didn't understand your question.

Comment: `(\s*)` and `(?! wordc)` are both captures, I'm asking is there a reason they are captures

Comment: @mrres1 (?!) is non-capturing.

Comment: @mrres1 http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html. 'The lookahead itself is not a capturing group'. You can try it.

Answer (score 63):

Your regex should work 'as-is'. Assuming that it is doing what you want it to.

```
wordA(\s*)wordB(?! wordc)
```

This means match `wordA` followed by 0 or more spaces followed by `wordB`, but **do not match** if followed by `wordc`. Note the single space between `?!` and `wordc` which means that `wordA wordB wordc` will not match, but `wordA wordB    wordc` will.

Here are some example matches and the associated replacement output:

[image]

Note that all matches are replaced no matter how many spaces. There are a couple of other points: -

- `(?! wordc)` is a negative lookahead, so you wont match lines `wordA wordB wordc` which is assume is intended (and is why the last line is not matched). Currently you are relying on the space after `?!` to match the whitespace. You may want to be more precise and use `(?!\swordc)`. If you want to match against more than one space before wordc you can use `(?!\s*wordc)` for 0 or more spaces or `(?!\s*+wordc)` for 1 or more spaces depending on what your intention is. 
  **Of course, if you do want to match lines with wordc after wordB then you shouldn't use a negative lookahead.**
- `*` will match 0 or more spaces so it will match wordAwordB. You may want to consider `+` if you want at least one space.
- `(\s*)` - the brackets indicate a capturing group. Are you capturing the whitespace to a group for a reason? If not you could just remove the brackets, i.e. just use `\s`.

**Update based on comment**

> > Hello the problem is not the expression but the HTML out put   that are not considered as whitespace. it's a Joomla website.

Preserving your original regex you can use:

```
wordA((?:\s|&nbsp;)*)wordB(?!(?:\s|&nbsp;)wordc)
```

The only difference is that not the regex matches whitespace OR `&nbsp;`. I replaced `wordc` with `\swordc` since that is more explicit. Note as I have already pointed out that the negative lookahead `?!` will *not* match when wordB is followed by a single whitespace and wordc. If you want to match multiple whitespaces then see my comments above. I also preserved the capture group around the whitespace, if you don't want this then remove the brackets as already described above.

Example matches:

[image]

Comment: Hello  the problem is not the expression but the HTML out put &nbsp; that are not considered as whitespace. it's a Joomla website. Any idea. thank you for your help.

Comment: @user3344311 - see my update, I will add some examples shortly.

Answer (score 2):

The reason I used a `+` instead of a '*' is because a plus is defined as one or more of the preceding element, where an asterisk is zero or more.  In this case we want a delimiter that's a little more concrete, so "one or more" spaces.

```
word[Aa]\s+word[Bb]\s+word[Cc]
```

will match:

```
wordA wordB     wordC
worda wordb wordc
wordA   wordb   wordC
```

The words, in this expression, will have to be specific, and also in order (a, b, then c)

Comment: The pipe doesn't have a special meaning inside a character class, it is a literal character. A character class is only a set of characters. Writing `[A|a]` is exactly the same than `[|aA]` or `[aA|]`. You can replace this with `[aA]` or, why not `(?:a|A)`.